# I want to upload a document to sharepoint 2010 then ask me who it to be approved by

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, approval-process

When I upload a document into a document library,  I want SharePoint to let me decide who to send it to for approval.  When I create a workflow it asks me to fill in a name. I don't want this because each document could be for a different person out of the 200 employees we have.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new field in the document list that will contain the email address of the person you want to approve the document.  When uploading a new document, it will prompt the user to input an email address (or you could set it up to find it in an address book).  In your workflow, you can then use this field to set the email address of the approvar.

So now you can specify the user to send the email to when creating the document.